# Can't remove values in Firebase realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I want to remove a node (~13mb) from my realtime database. I use cli with `firebase database:remove '/node'` but i am getting `An unexpcted error`. Debug file says:

```
[debug] [2020-09-30T10:17:16.845Z] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at validateString (internal/validators.js:122:11)
at Url.parse (url.js:159:3)
at urlParse (url.js:154:13)
at Url.resolve (url.js:667:29)
at Object.urlResolve [as resolve] (url.js:663:40)
at Object.getDatabaseUrl (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/utils.js:62:26)
at Command.actionFn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/database-remove.js:33:32)
at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:166:25)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

When i do a `firebase database:get '/node'` i am getting the correct values.

I already updated firebase-tools and did a new init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem today and submitted this as an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2667

I manually added a trivial key to the database and `firebase database:remove` had the same problem attempting to remove it.

Hopefully others there can reproduce and solve it.

(I would have commented this if I had the reps... But perhaps watching the issue get addressed over there is the true answer anyway )

**Edit:** Resolved with [Changelog for database:remove command fix #2658](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2658) merged into master and released in [version 8.12.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.12.0) -
Works great